# How to perform rowcount with a web service in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: javascript, web-services, rest, soap

Pagination loses some of it's luster with no knowledge of the total number of results. Is it possible to perform a "row count" with either REST or SOAP (getListItems) without getting back all of the items (eg: a request truncated with $top)?

Ideally you would request `/_vti_bin/listData.svc/myList?$top=2` and get back 2 results and a count of the total. Is there any at all to accomplish this is SP2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a REST call like `_vti_bin/Listdata.svc/YourList/$count` and it should return the number of items in the list.

http://mstecharchitect.blogspot.com/2010/01/accessing-sharepoint-2010-lists-using.html

Comment: That is perfect. It's unfortunate that the total isn't attached to all REST calls `d.__count` but hey, at the cost of another call as least it's accessible. Thank you very much!

Comment: Bonus points if you can tell me where something like this would be documented? Silly me, I thought I'd find an API in the MSDN, but apparently scattering tidbits across the blogosphere is the MS version of developer relations.

Comment: Sadly, that link is dead or hijacked to a non useful page. :(

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question.  But thought I would add to it with the specific syntax needed for using `$count` and `$filter` together, to achieve the total number of records based on some criteria.

In this example, I want to get the total number of Orders that were created by user ID 2:

```
http://yourdomain.com/sitecollection/site/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Orders/$count/?$filter=CreatedById eq 2
```

Hope that helps someone.